# Amazon SP-API: what are the steps I should follow to finally being able to use it

Tags: node.js, amazon-selling-partner-api

I've been reading in circles the amazon sp-api documentation, I've done a ton of registration, developer profile, seller account, developer account etc

```
https://developercentral.amazon.com/

https://developer.amazon.com/

https://sellercentral.amazon.com/
```

I'm still not able to get the credentials I need to integrate this on the app I'm working to allow users to their data through my app using OAuth.
Anyone knows what to do?

What I need is being able to create the OAuth flow so I can linked user's sellers account in my app so they can have access to their information

The endpoints: https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/website-authorization-workflow

but for that I need an app that accepts OAuth authorizations, right now I'm only allowed to do self-authorizations

I'm not sure if the registration I did was wrong, if I need more registration, what should I do?

Comment: Creating the OAuth flow in your application is your responsibility. You must implement it, test with your own account, and submit for approval when it's all working.

Comment: Sorry I expressed myself wrongly, what I need are the credentials and a public app from amazon and their approval for that, the flow itself I already know how to do it. My biggest problem is that there are so many places the documentation send you when you're reading it that I'm not sure what registrations do I really need for that